# How to work with specific column without iterating each row with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have found answers to add a column with jQuery in specific locations, using a syntax like this:

```
    $('table').find('tr').each(function(){
        $(this).find('td').eq(0).after('<td>cell 1a</td>');
    });
```

But what I would like to do is insert a column for the first and last row, without iterating through eac row:

```
$('table').find('tr').eq(0).magic(function() {
     $(this).find('td:last').after('<td>foo</td>');
});
```

How can I do this, and replace `magic` with something jQuery does?

Using `$('table').find('tr').eq(0).find("td:last").after('<td>foo</td>');` works fine to edit a specific row. So it looks like the issue is somewhere else in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Something has to iterate over every row to add a column as that's just how tables work.  You can use a little more selector power and do something like this:

```
$('table tr').find("td:last").after('<td>foo</td>');
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3zfwrg8p/

---

Or, using `.append()` (since you're adding at the end of the row):

```
$('table tr').append('<td>foo</td>');
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/osbn218w/

Comment: The jsfiddle works fine when I use `$('table').find('tr').eq(0).find("td:last").after('<td>foo</td>');`. I thought it was my syntax that was wrong, but clearly, it is something else, because it doesn't work in my code!

Comment: @Phil - your code is only adding a column to the first row.  I though you wanted to add a column to every row.  Other than that, it's basically the same as my first option - I just combined to operations into one selector.

Comment: I only have 2 rows, and need to add a column to each, while iterating over the data. That's why I cannot iterate over the rows.

Comment: Found the issue with Firebug.My table was incorrectly formatted, so it was looking for the row in the wrong place. Thanks though, your jsfiddle helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use append and it will add the td at the end of the selector

```
$('table').find('tr').each(function(){
    $(this).append('<td>and a </td>');
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o653zyL5/)